# Adding boundary conditions to linear regression model

Tags: r, lm

Is it possible to add boundary condtions to `lm()` model in R?

```
weight <- data.frame(mass = c(0.02, 0, 0.3, 0.05, 0.006, 0.01), size = c(0.5, 0.001, 0.1, 0.2, 0.06, 0.02), density = c(1, 0, 0.05, 0.012, 0.1, 0.01))

t <- lm(mass  ~ size + density, data = weight)
```

For example if `result < 0` then `result = 0`? - because it is impossible to have mass less than zero.

I have found some information after writing `?lm` but there are no examples how to use it.

> model, x, y, qr    logicals. If TRUE the corresponding components of the
>   fit (the model frame, the model matrix, the response, the QR
>   decomposition) are returned.

I can run the model and check the result for boundary conditions after it compiles but maybe there is more elegant way :)

```
result <- t$residuals + weight$mass
check <- function(x){
  if(x < 0){
    return(0)
  }
    return(x)
}
sapply(result, check)
```

Comment: Note that your check for boundary conditions could be made more elegant (and computationally faster) as `result <- pmax(fitted(t), 0)`- does that help?

Comment: @Patronus I was thinking about implementing it inside `lm` because of summary function - I have lots of models in a loop an collecting output parameters directly from model parameters is much faster

Comment: @plotr What does the output of the predicted values (what you're setting to zero) have to do with the summary function()? The summary output doesn't contain the fitted values. Or is it your concern that the slope and intercept could be different (which they could indeed, if there are mass predicted values that would be negative!)

Comment: @Patronus sorry I meant coefficients, I am not sure wheather it is most efficient and mathematicaly correct to use fitted model with fitted coefficients and after that check for boundaries - but in foreacasting future values still useing fitted coefficients (and boundary statement after that).
Or maybe I should first fit the model, then check for boundary conditions and then fitt the model again to fitt it within boundary conditions ?

Comment: Wouldn't a [truncated regression](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/truncated-regression/) be applicable here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no longer a linear model since the output would have a bend in it, so you can't use `lm`. However, you could approach this with the `nls` function (nonlinear least squares), using `pmax` in your formula.

To demonstrate this, let's simplify the data so that it has only one predictor (easier to graph), and that the line clearly would go below zero.

```r
weight <- data.frame(mass = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3), size = c(1, 3, 4, 6, 5))

# simple linear model
mod_linear <- lm(mass  ~ size, data = weight)

# nls; note that you had to take guesses for the parameters.
mod_nls <- nls(mass ~ pmax(intercept + b1 * size, 0),
           weight, start = list(intercept = 0, b1 = 1))
```

The coefficients of the model are then substantially different:

```
coefficients(summary(mod_linear))
#>               Estimate Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) -0.9054054  0.9404279 -0.962759 0.40668973
#> size         0.5540541  0.2254503  2.457544 0.09106616
coefficients(summary(mod_nls))
#>           Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)
#> intercept     -2.1  1.6062378 -1.307403 0.282250
#> b1             0.8  0.3464102  2.309401 0.104088
```

You could see the difference in the predictions by graphing both (and see that the nonlinear version is a better model for the data).

```
library(ggplot2)
weight$linear <- predict(mod_linear)
weight$nonlinear <- predict(mod_nls)

ggplot(weight, aes(size, mass)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = linear), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = nonlinear), color = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :) PS. is there a way to optimize process of selecting nls parameters - to choose the best possible autmaticaly?

Comment: @piotr Great! Not in the general case, but in this case I'd recommend starting with your lm() parameters; they will likely be close enough. (In a two parameter model as simple as this, I imagine it would be hard to get it so far off the model doesn't converge)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a log link function to do this. Try using `glm()` specifying a log link.